# How to use function from file which use node.js in client file?

Tags: javascript, node.js

**_api.js**

`

```
const fs = require('fs')

const databasePath = "/database/db.json"

function addUser(user) {
  fs.readFile(databasePath, (err, content) => {
    if (!err) {
      const DATABASE = JSON.parse(content)
      const USERS = DATABASE.users

      DATABASE.amount += 1

      USERS[`${DATABASE.amount}`] = {
        name: user.name,
        password: user.password,
      }

      fs.writeFile(databasePath, JSON.stringify(DATABASE), (err) => {
        if (err) {
          throw err
        }

        console.log('Content of database file:')

        const DATA = fs.readFileSync(databasePath, 'utf8').toString()

        console.log(DATA)
      })
    }
  })
}

module.exports = { addUser }
```

`

**client.js**
`

```
const DB = require('/api/_api.js')

// How to import the _api.js function???

const username = document.querySelector("#username")
const password = document.querySelector("#password")
const submit = document.querySelector("#submit")


submit.addEventListener('click', () => {
    const user = {
        name: username.value,
        password: password.value
    }

    DB.addUser(user)
})
```

`

How to import the _api.js function addUser() in client.js file?

I try to use require() - error (you cant use require in client file).
I try to use import - error (Cannot use import statement outside a module).

Comment: When I try to require _api.js in file I get an error like - "You cant use require in client file"

Comment: In short, you can't use node.js in browser.

Comment: Even tho you can fix particular error with changing `require` to EcmaScript Module [import](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/import), you're not allowed to use `fs` (I/O) package of client side.

Comment: I want use function in other file if user click on button.

Comment: You have got to transport the user data over HTTP to the server, and let the server add the user tot the database. You can use a webserver for this, like express, hapi, koa or whatever.

Answer (score 0):

You have to send the data from the client to the server via HTTP, for example using JSON. Use a webserver for this purpose, like express. The webserver can also host the html and javascript files that are meant for the client.

Here is a small example:

```
const express = require('express');
const bodyParser = require('body-parser');
const app = express();
const port = 3000;

// Enable Express to parse json requests and receve them in the req.body
// property.
app.use(bodyParser.json());

// Host the main page. Ideally you want to serve a static folder with
// client html and javacsript using app.use(express.static('some/folder'))
app.get('/', (req, res) => {
  res.send(`
  <!DOCTYPE html>
  <html lang="en">
  <head>
  <title>Page Title</title>
  </head>
  <body>

    <form id="credentials">
        Name: <input id="username" name="username" type="text"><br/>    
        Password: <input id="password" name="password" type="password"><br/>    
        <input value="Submit" type="submit"><br/>    
    </form>
  
  <script>
    // I put the script below the html so the elements are loaded in DOM
    // before trying to grab them using javascript

    // grab the form element
    document.querySelector('#credentials')

      // add the form submit handler
      .addEventListener('submit', function(e) {

      // prevent the form from being submitted by the browser
      // which would result in a page reload.
      e.preventDefault();
      
      // grab the user data
      const username = document.querySelector('#username').value;
      const password = document.querySelector('#password').value;
      const body = { username, password };
      console.log('Sending: ', body);

      // Use the fetch method for sending the data via a POST 
      // request. For more info:
      // https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API/Using_Fetch
      fetch('/credentials', {
        method: 'post',
        headers: {
          'Content-Type': 'application/json'
        },

        // convert the body to a string since HTTP is plain text
        body: JSON.stringify(body)
      })

      // parse the response to an javascript object and log it
      .then(response => response.json())
      .then(response => console.log(response))
    });
  </script>

  </body>
  </html>
  `);
})

// Register the post request handler for receiving the 
// user credentials.
app.post('/credentials', (req, res) => {
  console.log('Received: ', req.body);

  // Do your db stuff here...

  // tell the client everything went well.
  res.send(JSON.stringify({'success': true})); 
})

// Start the webserver
app.listen(port, () => {
  console.log(`Example app listening on port ${port}`)
})
```

Run the script and navigate your browser to http://localhost:3000